# How to add two geoJSON feature collections in to two layer groups

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have two geoJSON feature collections that I need to add to the map, and I also want them to be toggled on and off via the layer visibility controllers as shown in http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html

how can I do this?

Comment: Check the source code on how it was done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is also a very good tutorial on the usage of `L.GeoJSON`, Leaflet's GeoJSON layer, which can be found here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html and here is the reference for `L.GeoJSON`: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson You already found the tutorial on `L.control.layers`, here is the reference for it: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers

It's actually quite simple to do, it's just a matter of creating a layercontrol, loading a GeoJSON file into your script by using your favorite XHR library, use the retrieved data to defined a `L.GeoJSON` layer and add it to the layercontrol. In code:

```
// Create the layercontrol and add it to the map
var controlLayers = L.control.layers().addTo(map);

// Loading a GeoJSON file (using jQuery's $.getJSON)    
$.getJSON('/my-folder/my-file.json', function (data) {

  // Use the data to create a GeoJSON layer and add it to the map
  var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);

  // Add the geojson layer to the layercontrol
  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'My GeoJSON layer title');

});
```

A working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tFVrrq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Since you create a layer when loading a GeoJSON, you can add it to the layer control as an Overlay Layer (simply modify that example and replace the cities layer.